# write get request one time in all app - swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to write a protocol for http get requests and use it in my view controllers. The idea is to prevent writing request in each VC and write it once in app. I wrote a protocol with get function and wrote an extension for it to implement get request using Alamofire.

```
protocol Irequest
{
    func getRequest(url: String, completion: (JSON) -> ())
    func postRequest(url: String, param: Parameters, completion: (JSON) -> ())
}

extension Irequest
{
    func getRequest(url: String, completion:@escaping (JSON) -> ())
    {

Alamofire.request(url.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlFragmentAllowed)!, method: .post)
    .responseJSON { response in
            debugPrint(response)
            if let Json = response.result.value
            {
                let j = JSON(Json)
                completion(j)
            }
            else
            {
                completion(JSON("{}"))
            }
    }
}

}
```

Now, when i wanna use it in my class it say class X doesn't conform protocol Irequest. How can i use it? and in more general term, how can i have one get request function in all app?

```
class X : UIViewController , Irequest
```

Comment: Actually, you can just put this function in the global scope, can't you?

Comment: The error *does not conform* occurs because `postRequest` is not implemented. I suppose an extension of `UIViewController` is more suitable than a protocol.

Comment: @vadian you're right. I commented postRequest in protocol but still says doesn't conform protocol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.
the protocol's get method signature is != the extension's get signature. one has no @escaping, one does.

==> methods don't match, ergo get isn't there

2.
post isn't implemented at all

==> ergo method is missing

---

from the comments you already know about 2 so fix 1 and you should be good :)